# Missing something in multiple subquery structure

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am trying to do a simple count of records from 2 tables. I have done this several times before, however I can't currently access my usual system. I am sure I am missing the simplest thing, but I am stressed out and can't find an answer anywhere.

I know when I am pulling from one table it works just fine. I think I am just missing a stupid comma or something.

My query isn't showing up right. Here is a photo.

SELECT 
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    T1 AS ct_hipotdb,
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    T2 AS task_resultdb

```
(SELECT 
    *
FROM
    ct_hipot
WHERE
    ACTOR_NAME LIKE ('MFG%')
        AND CONVERT_TZ(TIME_STAMP, 'UTC', 'US/Pacific') BETWEEN '2019/6/3 06:00:00' AND '2019/6/4 06:00:00') T1
(SELECT 
    *
FROM
    task_result
WHERE
    ACTOR_NAME LIKE ('MFG%')
        AND CONVERT_TZ(task_TIMESTAMP, 'UTC', 'US/Pacific') BETWEEN '2019/6/3 06:00:00' AND '2019/6/4 06:00:00') T2
```

[QueryPhoto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNgFW.jpg)

Comment: It's a bit unclear for us what are you trying to do. Might be UNION of JOIN. Syntax would be different.

Comment: Just how my day is going It's not showing up right. I'll attach a photo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missed your first part that was not displayed as code.
Something like this:

```
SELECT
      (
        SELECT
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            ct_hipot
        WHERE
                ACTOR_NAME LIKE ('MFG%')
            AND CONVERT_TZ(TIME_STAMP, 'UTC', 'US/Pacific') BETWEEN '2019/6/3 06:00:00' AND '2019/6/4 06:00:00'
    ) AS ct_hipotdb
    , (
        SELECT
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            task_result
        WHERE
                ACTOR_NAME LIKE ('MFG%')
            AND CONVERT_TZ(task_TIMESTAMP, 'UTC', 'US/Pacific') BETWEEN '2019/6/3 06:00:00' AND '2019/6/4 06:00:00'
    ) AS task_resultdb
;
```

?

P.S. I would not use CONVERT_TZ function like you did as this will prevent the query to use index. You should convert constants from your TZ to UTZ instead.

Comment: Yes. That was it. Thank you so much.